# Kinivo BTD-300 Bluetooth 3.0 dongle driver driver NOT on Kinivo site

Tags: windows-7, usb, drivers, bluetooth, dongle

*Relevant Specs:*
**OS:** Win7 Home Premium
**Machine:** Acer Aspire 6676-7739g w/RAM upgraded to 8GB

*Preamble:*
I purchased a few months ago a [Kinivo BTD-300 Bluetooth 3.0 USB dongle](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B005Z5HT2M), and thus far have had very little issue with it. Today however, the thing didn't want to connect to my Bluetooth headset like it's been doing ever since I bought it, so I removed the headset from Bluetooth devices intending to re-pair it. However, the system wouldn't find the headset, despite being right next to each other and both devices being discoverable. In my very-ticked-off-from-something-else state, I've no idea why I thought uninstalling the dongle would be a good idea, but I did, and now when I try reinstalling, the system DOES NOT recognize the dongle, and the Kinivo support site DOES NOT offer the files in the mini-CD that comes with the device.

The "fun" part is that for reasons unrelated to this question, I no longer have the box/blister where the device came when I bought it, which had the disc with the drivers inside.

*The Question:*
Does anybody here happen to have the same BT dongle that can facilitate me a copy of the files in the included CD for this device via ISO or some other way? I realize this is partly my own fault for not backing up the drivers from the included disc, but considering that ***I had saved the box with all its contents, even the instruction manual*** until my work room got "cleaned up" by the maid, I did not even come close to suspecting I'd EVER lose that box. Now I'm stuck with a completely useless dongle that Win7 won't install, and despite my extensive Google-fu, these drivers apparently don't exist ANYWHERE on the internet.

Answer (score 0):

I have the cd. Do you still need it?

Also, it looks like you can get the drivers online now:
https://support.kinivo.com/customer/portal/articles/664950-downloads#computer